# Angularjs dirty state management and field re-use

Tags: forms, angularjs, validation, breeze

Angular.js manages form fields dirty state at field level and at form level: If I enter something in a form field, this field gets dirty and the form will also become dirty.

In our project we use the form fields dirty state, to highlight already touched fields using css class ng-dirty.

That all is fine as long as we have exact one form field for one model value.

But a typical usecase is an array of elements in the model. And in a (detail) form the items shall be managed.

Starting to edit one of them causes the corresponding form field to get dirty. That's fine.

Now, if the next entry is edited, the form is filled with it's values. But now the form elements dirty state and the models value dirty state is out of sync: The form field is dirty, the model value is not.

I wonder why angular uses the form field dirty state instead of the model value dirty state to set the classes in the form. Are there plans to change this in the future?

What could be an elegant way to solve problems like this? I thougt about using breeze.js together with angular, but I still don't know enough about breeze, if it could help me here.

Comment: It is rather unclear what you mean... What is the _"model's dirty state"_ ? There is no such thing (unless you build it yourself. And there are ways to set the "dirty" state of a field as well, in case you want different behaviour than Angular's default.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I know that the model has no dirty state out of the box. But when a model value is changed, (independent of a user interaction) the model can be regarded as dirty, until the model is saved - that is, what I meant. Wouldn't it be better to indicate the field and form's dirty state in dependence of any kind of "model's dirty state" instead of the state of an physical input field? - I know also, I can set a field to dirty or to pristine manually, but I wonder if there is already a better solution.

Comment: No, it wouldn't be possible for Angular to keep track of "model dirty state", because a.) it is model agnostic and b.) it doesn't know what is the "pristine" state of the model. Nevertheless, it is not difficult to keep pristine reference and check your model against it to determine if it is dirty. (There examples of such implementations in the Angular docs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my case i've used breeze to indicate validation errors directly at control level.
validation rules are defined per model. i'm pretty sure you can solve your requirement using breeze. take a look at: http://www.breezejs.com/breeze-labs/breezedirectivesvalidation

Comment: Thank you for sharing this link, I will dive deeper soon, but a quick view let me think that could help to solve this.